# Crawl image sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I need to create an `Employee Birthday list` that shows which employees have their birthday in the current month.

I created a custom list to store this info and crawled those columns that I made but when I was trying to crawl the photo there is no option for that to be crawled.

I need to display photo, department and birthday date, but I only have problems with the image, for that I'm using a `Content Search WebPart`. I'm really new working with SharePoint and really appreciate a lot if someone can help me or tell me the way or where can i find a solution for this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked at using the User Profile Service instead? All the information, Name, department, birthday (optionally) and photo are stored there.

Comment: yeah it works for the list, but when i'm going to use the property in the content search webpart i dont know how to crawl the image

Comment: The persons photo URL is a property of the User Profile just like PreferredName.

Answer (score 2):

This might not answer your question.

Search is not real time. In your case it's a single list and you can query the list using CAML. To optimise performance you can index the fields you are querying.

Comment: wow uhmm do you know any guide of that?